# Relationship between the feasible set and the domain of the objective function in constrained optimization problems

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

Let's look at the constrained optimization problem:

$ \displaystyle \min_{\mathbf{x} \in S} f(\mathbf{x})$

I have looked through several optimization textbooks and in all of them the relationship between the feasible set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the domain of the objective function $f(\mathbf{x})$ is described rather poorly. These books just say that $f$ should be defined on $S$ or on some set which contains $S$ (i.e. $S \subseteq \operatorname{dom} f \subset \mathbb{R}^n$). The problem with these textbooks is that they have several theorems which look like

> If the objective function $f(\mathbf{x})$ is continuously differentiable on the feasible set $S$, then ... (some statement)

Sometimes these theorems have some additional requirements on the feasible set $S$ (convex set/close set/open set, etc.). And sometimes they require $f$ to be convex or to be twice continuously differentiable on $S$.
**I want to know what does the following statement usually mean in optimization textbooks: "the objective function $f(\mathbf{x})$ is continuously differentiable on the feasible set $S$" ?**
The problem is that the set $S$ is not necessarily open, and in my calculus textbooks there is a definition of continuous differentiability only for the case of an open set. So I am highly confused now.

My guess is that optimization textbooks (at least for undergraduate students) implicitly assume two things:

1. $S \subseteq \operatorname{int} \operatorname{dom} f \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
2. The statement "the objective function $f(\mathbf{x})$ is continuously differentiable on the feasible set $S$" means that $f(\mathbf{x})$ is continuously differentiable in every point of $S$ (i.e. for each point $\mathbf{x} \in S$ we have that all first-order partial derivatives of $f$ are defined in some its neighborhood $U(\mathbf{x})$ and are continuous in $\mathbf{x}$).

Is my guess correct?

Comment: It is a point that many discussion gloss over, and is mildly bothersome if you care about details (I do). I interpret it to mean that there is some continuous function $\Delta$ (think $Df$) defined on $S$ such that the Frechet condition holds (as in the $\epsilon,\delta$ condition with $\|f(x+h)-f(x)-\Delta(x)h\| \le \epsilon \|x\|$). Note that $S$ may be such that the partials do not exist just because of the shape of $S$. If $S$ is 'full enough' (whatever that means) at a point then we must have $\Delta(x) = Df(x)$.